# IndexOutOfBoundsException on a NinePatch

Tags: android, android-layout, nine-patch

I get this strange error in `Graphical Layout` tab on eclipse when I set the background of my view to this specific NinePatch image.

I get the error only when I want to preview an xhdpi or xxhdpi layout. On ldpi, mdpi and hdpi it previews fine.

Any ideas?

```
fragment_main.xml: Index: 0, Size: 0

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
    at com.android.ninepatch.NinePatchChunk.draw(NinePatchChunk.java:185)
    at com.android.ninepatch.NinePatchChunk.draw(NinePatchChunk.java:101)
    at android.graphics.NinePatch_Delegate$1.draw(NinePatch_Delegate.java:242)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.GcSnapshot.drawInLayer(GcSnapshot.java:613)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.GcSnapshot.draw(GcSnapshot.java:583)
    at android.graphics.NinePatch_Delegate.draw(NinePatch_Delegate.java:239)
    at android.graphics.NinePatch_Delegate.nativeDraw(NinePatch_Delegate.java:187)
    at android.graphics.NinePatch.nativeDraw(NinePatch.java)
    at android.graphics.NinePatch.drawSoftware(NinePatch.java:172)
    at android.graphics.Canvas.drawPatch(Canvas.java:1103)
    at android.graphics.NinePatch.draw(NinePatch.java:163)
    at android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable.draw(NinePatchDrawable.java:229)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14450)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14350)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14348)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14350)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:584)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:338)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:504)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1584)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1309)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener.reloadLayoutSwt(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1817)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener.access$0(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1755)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener$1.run(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1749)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3946)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3623)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_landingpage_gradient" />
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: why are you having such a large picture?

Comment: It's the version that I would use for xhdpi screens. It's part of the design

Comment: but y not making te height very much smaller? it will stretch on that point u marked in ninepatch. Have you created it with the ninepatch tool?

Comment: This design is completely wrong. It shows a serious misunderstanding of how 9 patches work.

Comment: Having a smaller 9patch resolved the issue, but I still don't understand why it would give that error.

Answer (score 2):

The image is way too high. It repeats the same pixel over and over again, that is *exactly* what nine patches do.

If it's a gradient (judging from the name, hard to say with the image) use XML to create it. It will look a lot nicer and costs almost no storage.

As for the original error, my guess is that it's just too many repeated pixels. But that's just a guess.

Comment: Since the gradient has at least 4 colours involved it can't be created easily in xml. I managed to solve the issue by having a smaller (in height) png. But I still don't understand why it would show that error.

Comment: I guess the 9patch buffer has a certain length and you exceeded that.