# Android Layout throwing error Index: 0,size: 0

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to create a layout so that I can provide some values to fields. But Android studio throwing an error saying Index :0, Size :0.

I have not added any content with associated activity class but I'm facing this error.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".service.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/goods_description_cv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/close_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="330dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/close_icon"
                android:src="@drawable/close_ic"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/item_name_dv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/add_item"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/bundles_dv"
                android:layout_width="63dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/add_bundles"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/add_code_dv"
                android:layout_width="69dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/add_code"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:labelFor="@+id/hsn_code_et"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/hsn_code_dv"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:autofillHints="no"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/add_hsn_code"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:labelFor="@+id/hsn_code_et"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/quantity_dv"
                android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/add_quantity"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/rate_dv"
                android:layout_width="67dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/add_rate"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textAlignment="textStart" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/taxable_value_dv"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/add_taxable_value"
                android:importantForAutofill="no"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:textAlignment="textStart" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Error as below:

[image]

Even after refreshing the same error appear again.

Can someone help to resolve this issue?

Comment: You are  missing this```</LinearLayout>```

Comment: @SuhaibRaadan can you be more specific. When I checked I have closed all <LinearLayout> tags

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684868/indexoutofboundsexception-on-a-ninepatch

Comment: @SuhaibRaadan thanks for your answer. But this is different from what I'm facing. The above error might be at run time of App, but I'm getting just in Layout ( Not causing any abnormal termination)

Comment: I got an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63552928/android-4-0-1-xml-rendering-error-in-edittext-index0-size-0-vew-draw-fai